# How do I use "Baby Steps" in a sentence

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I want to convey that I am putting myself to something new to achieve a dream/goal. Hence I thought of using the phrase "baby steps" in a sentence as follows: "As I am laying my Baby Steps towards becoming a ..."

I am wondering if this a right way to use "Baby Steps". If not, please let me know how do I put these words to convey what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: Try *making baby steps*.

Comment: I doubt you mean you want to use "baby steps" as a verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that *baby steps* is a [**metaphor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor): it compares initial stages of a new endeavor to the very small and stumbling steps of a child just learning to walk.

And when you employ a metaphor you should keep your language consistent with the image you are evoking, at least within the scope of the sentence in which you introduce it. (But if you try to extend the metaphor into further sentences it becomes a “conceit”, a ruling concept. This is difficult to sustain for any length of time, and is likely to appear contrived.)

Consequently, *laying baby steps* is inappropriate: we do not speak of *laying* steps except in stonemasonry, where *steps* means surfaces on which to step rather than the physical acts designated in *baby steps*.

Usually we speak of *taking* steps:

> John took a step toward the door.

The idiom *take steps* is also used in a figurative or metaphorical sense to mean *take positive action*:

> The government is taking steps to reduce the incidence of violent crime.
>   We should take steps to improve communication between the two departments.

So marrying these two expressions, *baby steps* and *take steps*, would be particularly felicitous in your context:

> As I take baby steps towards becoming a ...